MVVM Custom Splash page and don't go back on Login page in .NET Maui
I have custom splash page that will do some work and after finish, it will navigate to Login page. From login page, I don't want it to be able to go back to splash page. Currently when I click go back on Android and WinUI at login page, it will go back to splash page again.
App.xaml.cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    private readonly Interfaces.INavigationService _navigationService;
    public App(Interfaces.INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new AppShell(_navigationService);
    }
}

AppShell.xaml.cs
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    private readonly Interfaces.INavigationService _navigationService;
    public AppShell(Interfaces.INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        InitializeRouting();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override async void OnHandlerChanged()
    {
        base.OnHandlerChanged();
        if (Handler is not null)
        {
            await _navigationService.InitializeAsync();
        }
    }
    private static void InitializeRouting()
    {
        Routing.RegisterRoute("Splash", typeof(SplashView));
        Routing.RegisterRoute("Login", typeof(LoginView));
        Routing.RegisterRoute("MauiSample", typeof(MauiSample));
        Routing.RegisterRoute("MainTrans", typeof(MainTransView));
    }
}

MauiProgram.cs
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    => MauiApp
        .CreateBuilder()
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
            .UseMaterialComponents()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            })
            .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
            {
#if ANDROID
                handlers.AddHandler(typeof(Entry), typeof(MauiApps.Platforms.Android.MyEntryHandler));
#endif
            })
            .RegisterAppServices()
            .RegisterViewModels()
            .RegisterViews()
            .Build();

    public static MauiAppBuilder RegisterAppServices(this MauiAppBuilder mauiAppBuilder)
    {
        mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<ISettingsService, SettingsService>();
        mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<INavigationService, MauiNavigationService>();
        mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<IDialogService, DialogService>();
        return mauiAppBuilder;
    }
    public static MauiAppBuilder RegisterViewModels(this MauiAppBuilder mauiAppBuilder)
    {
        mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>();
        mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddTransient<SplashViewModel>();
        mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddTransient<LoginViewModel>();
        mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddTransient<MauiSampleViewModel>();
        mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddTransient<MainTransViewModel>();
        return mauiAppBuilder;
    }
    public static MauiAppBuilder RegisterViews(this MauiAppBuilder mauiAppBuilder)
    {
        mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddTransient<SplashView>();
        mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddTransient<LoginView>();
        mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddTransient<MauiSample>();
        mauiAppBuilder.Services.AddTransient<MainTransView>();
        return mauiAppBuilder;
    }

SplashViewModel.cs
public partial class SplashViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _splashInfoText = "";

    public SplashViewModel(INavigationService navigationService) : base(navigationService)
    {

    }
    public override async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        await IsBusyFor(
            async () =>
            {
                /// This just sample to simulate background task to be added later
                await Task.Delay(50);
                SplashInfoText = "Load parameter file.";
                await Task.Delay(10);
                SplashInfoText = "Establish cloud connection.";
                await Task.Delay(20);
                SplashInfoText = "Checking configuration OK.";
                await Task.Delay(30);
                SplashInfoText = "Validate badge information.";
                await Task.Delay(30);
                SplashInfoText = "Verify permissions";
                await Task.Delay(10);
                SplashInfoText = "Check and update terminal.";
                await Task.Delay(60);
                SplashInfoText = "Run a quick test";
                await Task.Delay(30);
                SplashInfoText = "Perform inventory update";
                await Task.Delay(10);
                SplashInfoText = "Retrieve new parameter information";
                await Task.Delay(40);
                SplashInfoText = "Resolve unsend transaction";
                await Task.Delay(10);
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    SplashInfoText = $"Sending {Path.GetRandomFileName()}";
                    await Task.Delay(10);
                }
                SplashInfoText = "All file successfully uploaded";
                await Task.Delay(50);
                SplashInfoText = "Navigating to login sample screen";
                await Task.Delay(100);
                await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync("Login");
            });
    }
}

How do I modify my code to only set the MainPage = new AppShell(_navigationService); at LoginViewModel so that the starting app should be history to Login as first page.

Target platform to install=ANDROID.
Target to develop=WinUI,ANDROID.
Target planned environment=ANDROID,WinUI


You can try to add the following code before you navigate to LoginPage:
.....
var stack = Shell.Current.Navigation.NavigationStack.ToArray();
for(int i = stack.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
   Shell.Current.Navigation.RemovePage(stack[i]);
}
await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync("Login");
.....

Update:
Separate SplashView from the AppShell and treat SplashView as a separate page. In App.xaml.cs:
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
 
        MainPage = new SplashView();
    }
}

Set MainPage to AppShell when you're ready to navigate:
.....
SplashInfoText = "Navigating to login sample screen";
await Task.Delay(100);
App.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
.....

About design of AppShell, you can see my answer of case: How do you replace a page with another in MAUI?.

The stack return {Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Page[1]} . So it not go to for loop to remove page.

I update the answer, wish it can help you :)

I got the interfaces. I'm following the way of eShopContainers sample. So, I keep the INavigationService using Shell.  I'm currently navigating in SplashViewModel to Login view

Actually, you can keep it simple, it doesn't need to be that complicated.

Actually because App.Current.MainPage = new AppShell(); having error in viewmodel. Plus I'm new with mvvm pattern. My guide was the sample application. If I'm changing to simple, I don't know how can I rewrite back the whole code if got error since all code was connected to each otherc with parameter.

Is it possible to separate SplashView？

I'm cool with it as long as I can do background task to load all configuration, send unsync data to ftp and everything else. This app will be running by our internal team project. So, the splash loading for getting everything that take times is not an issue for them as long when application is at login screen, they can start login and do their task. Currently, we are using Xamarin.Android and I want to explore possibility in .NET MAUI as alternative framework for Android

About Xamarin development, its support has ended on May 1, 2024. So, it is recommended to migrate Xamarin project to MAUI.

Our project is integrate with portable handheld device with usage of UHF, BARCODE and SAM. The library from manufacturer only serve JAR and DLL. I've read somewhere there is bit difference in XAMARIN and MAUI compatibility when initialize and passing the context, broadcasting and handler. Currently, I play around to understand about MVVM style while waiting for any library from manufacturer that support .NET8

The documentation describes Absolute routes, Relative routes and Backwards navigation.
Absolute routes
Navigation can be performed by specifying a valid absolute URI as an argument to the GoToAsync method:
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//Login");

Relative routes
Navigation can also be performed by specifying a valid relative URI as an argument to the GoToAsync method.
Backwards navigation
Backwards navigation with ".." can also be combined with a route:
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("../Login");

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-8.0 it distinguishes between:
